# How to use classes with mixins as types in typescipt

Tags: typescript, mixins

I have the following code

```js
type GConstructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
class Sprite {
  name = "";
  x = 0;
  y = 0;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  setPos(x:number, y:number) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y
  }
}
type Positionable = GConstructor<{ setPos: (x: number, y: number) => void }>;

function Jumpable<TBase extends Positionable>(Base: TBase) {
  return class Jumpable extends Base {
    jump() {
      this.setPos(0, 20);
    }
  };
}

const JumpableSprite = Jumpable(Sprite);

function hi(x: JumpableSprite) {
  return 4;
}
```

the problem is that I get this error

```
'JumpableSprite' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof JumpableSprite'?
Parameter 'x' of exported function has or is using private name 'JumpableSprite'.
```

I'm pretty sure I don't want `typeof JumpableSprite`, because I want it to be typed as `JumbableSprite` not `JumbableSprite`'s class.

Is there a way to use JumpableSprite as a type?

Comment: For the ```Jumpable``` function, you are returning a class. Try to make a type for the Jumpable return type which fits the parameter ```x``` 's type

Comment: Would this work?

type JumpableSprite = Sprite & {jump(): undefined};

Comment: If that's all I needed then, could you please post that as an answer so I can accept it? I think that's correct

Comment: Also, sorry if that was a really dumb question. I know JavaScript very well, but I'm pretty new to TypeScript so I've been able so figure most things out. I think shadowing names with Types like this will solve most of the problems I encounter. Thanks!

Comment: I've been trying that out in my project, and it seems to be working! The only issue is that I get an already defined eslint message when I Define a type that I already have the class for. Is that fixable?

Comment: What is your most updated code?

Comment: @tsecheukfung01 Sorry, I got it. It was [here](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-redeclare.md). It says to just use an es-lint disable line. Thanks again. If you make an answer, I will accept it, or I can do it

Comment: Glad that you have found it. If you do that, you can post the answer down below your question and tick it. Just let other who have similar question find the answer quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @tsecheukfung01 explained in the comments, all you have to do is create a type with the same name as the variable that refers to a class. After you have done this you will see an @typescript-eslint error (if you have @typescript-eslint in your project of course). Acording to the [@typescript-eslint docs](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-redeclare.md) you should just use an eslint ignore line. The complete working code...

```js
type GConstructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
class Sprite {
  name = "";
  x = 0;
  y = 0;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  setPos(x:number, y:number) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y
  }
}
type Positionable = GConstructor<{ setPos: (x: number, y: number) => void }>;

function Jumpable<TBase extends Positionable>(Base: TBase) {
  return class Jumpable extends Base {
    jump() {
      this.setPos(0, 20);
    }
  };
}

const JumpableSprite = Jumpable(Sprite);
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-redeclare -- intentionally naming the variable the same as the type
type JumpableSprite = Sprite & {jump(): undefined};

function hi(x: JumpableSprite) {
  return 4;
}
```